# CEdit in CDockablePane won't scroll

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Im using W7, VS2010: create an MDI app with the visual studio look so it has a `COutputWnd` inherited from `CDockablePane` at the bottom. Copying the default I've made a new tab, but inherited from `CEdit`. The tabs inherited from `CListBox` work great with the following styles:

```
const DWORD dwStyle = LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL;
```

But the `CEdit` with the following does not scroll vertically:

```
const DWORD dwStyle2 = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL;// | ES_READONLY;
```

I've tried all combinations of the above styles and read tons of websites, but nothing works :(

Oh - and I do have `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);`

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Ta-da! Got it sorted. In `COutputWnd::OnCreate` I had used `this` as the parent window:

```
m_wndVehicle->Create(dwStyle2, rectDummy, this, 3);
```

It should have been `&m_wndTabs`:

```
m_wndVehicle->Create(dwStyle2, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 3);
```

Works a treat now!

Hope it saves someone else 2 hours!